# Norm on $H^1/2(\partial\Omega)$ by first isomorphism theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, quotient-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I want to show that $\operatorname{ran}(T)$ equipped with
\begin{equation*}
\lVert v\rVert:=\inf\{u\in H^1(\Omega):Tu=v\}
\end{equation*}
is a Hilbert-Space.
I have seen that the definition of the norm is motivated by the norm on quotient spaces.
It was suggested to show that $\hat{T}:x+\ker(T)\mapsto T(x)$ is an isomorphism form $H^1(\Omega)/\ker(T)$ to $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, by applying the first Isomorphism Theorem.
How do I apply the Theorem without knowing that $\operatorname{ran}(T)$ is closed. I know that $\hat{T}$ is linear, bijective and continuous, how do I continue?

Comment: You want to show something like $V/W$ is a Banach space whenever $V$ is, and $W$ is a closed subspace. Then show that $\ker(T)$ is closed.